# java.io.IOException: Media was not found in the extent report while attacthing the screenshot in html report

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, appium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I get the screenshot in base64 format and while executing the test class ;it shows the error of Media was not found. Could anyone please do let me know where i am lacking in the code

Code:

```
public static String captureScreenAsBase64(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
        try {
            TakesScreenshot newScreen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            String scnShot = newScreen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
            return "data:image/jpg;base64, " + scnShot ;
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return screenshotName;
    }
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        logger.log(Status.FAIL,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        logger.log(Status.FAIL,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));

        String screenshotPath = TestUtil.captureScreenAsBase64(driver, result.getName());
        logger.fail("Snapshot below: " + logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));

    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        logger.log(Status.SKIP,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Skipped", ExtentColor.ORANGE));
    } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
        logger.log(Status.PASS,
                MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " Test Case PASSED", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
    extent.flush();
}

Exception:
java.io.IOException: Media was not found
```

Comment: output type of Base64 is a string.  Seems like you're expecting this string to be a filepath... but no file is created.  If you want a file use getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE) and then getAbsolutePath() on the File object for file path.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
logger.fail("Snapshot below: " + logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));
```

And trying to attach a base64 string to it. You need to use the method:

```
logger.addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64)
```

Note: you dont need this data:image/jpg;base64 as it will be done automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Try using an allure report. It is an open-source report as well and it supports multithreading in appium unlike extent report. The following code will attach a screenshot to the allure report on test failure,

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {
...
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
            try {
                byte[] screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                Allure.getLifecycle().addAttachment(your-screensout-filename, "image/png", "png", screenShot);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log("Exception occured while taking the screenshot");
            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: @foursyth Extent report is not threadsafe. I have seen it practicaly.